# Q: Multi-Tenant Azure API Management Design

Tags: azure, api, multi-tenant, azure-api-management

I have implemented a number of APIs on Azure APIM which are protected by a subscription key, and it all works fine.

I do have a constraint though, as the client application cannot be modified(*) and I can only set the URL as parameter (ie: no additional headers). I have worked around that limitation by implementing a small proxy app that customers can deploy locally and which adds the subscription key. In other words, the client app connects to a local URL, then the proxy calls the API. That also works fine.

I would like however to offer a simpler evaluation for prospects, without the need to deploy the proxy. I thought I could provide each customer their own tenant URL (eg: guid.mydomain.com) and then use that information on Azure APIM to look-up the auth key and call the backend API. That is the part I can't figure out.

I am looking for either alternative design ideas or tips on how to make it work.

Any idea?

Marco

(*) it belongs to another company.

Comment: I am still not sure what are you trying to achieve but multiple custom domain are available  in apim for the gateway endpoint in the premium tier. 
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/configure-custom-domain?tabs=custom

Comment: Thanks, I am aware of that. I would like to allow prospects to access the APIs by means of a sub-domain like guid.mydomain.com and use the guid to look-up the subscription key that I would then pass to the backend APIs.

Comment: if you use wildcard certificate you can do that but you have to create a custom domain for each client and that is not efficient approach at all and you will hit a limit there. Why not sending the subscription as path or query parameter (i.r /subscriptionKey or ?subscriptionKey = key). APIM gives you the option to send the key as a query parameter or as an header. Go under the api settings and see that option.

Comment: Thanks, but query parameters are not an option. the client application expects a URL that resolves to an IP address. indeed the idea is to create subdomains, not different domains per tenant.

Answer (score 0):

For those that may be interested, I solved the problem by adding a new set of azure functions and a custom wildcard certificate for the subdomain.

In the azure function, the domain and subdomain info can be found in the HttpRequest.Host property. In my case, the subdomain equates to the tenant id, which I can then use to retrieve the subscription key and call the APIM API.